# On the Formula: $V-E+F=2$

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

I am looking back at the history of the formula "$V-E+F=2$" for any polyhedron in Euclidean 3-space ($V=$number of vertices; $E=$ number of edges, $F=$ number of faces). Cauchy gave following proof of this theorem.

*Let P=the polyhedral, with V vertices, E edges, and F faces. To calculate V-E+F, remove one face, which will reduce $V-E+F$ by 1. Then, make any triangulation; this will not change $V-E+F$; then remove one by one faces whose one edge is also an edge of polyhedron; this will also not alter $V-E+F$. At last, we have one triangle, for which $V_1-E_1+F_1=1$; adding one both sides, LHS will be $V-E+F$ of original polyhedron, which is $2$, the RHS.*

This is the only proof I could saw now. I heard that Descartes, and Euler has also given proof of this theorem.

**Question 1.** How they (Descartes and Euler) proved it?

**Question** Instead of removing one face (in Cauchy's proof), can we remove one vertex, or one edge? More precisely, if P is a polyhedron, then by removing on vertex or one edge, can we "topologically" embed (deform) it into the plane?

Answer (score 2):

Euler proved it by constructing two trees out of the given Polyhedron (by the way $V+F-E = 2$ is valid for certain polyhedrons only).

One of the tree is the tree $T$ with vertices as the vertices from the polyhedron and edges (only a subset of course that are required to get the tree have all the vertices from the polyhedron) as edges from the polyhedron. The other tree $T^\prime$ is the dual of the tree $T$ - where the $T^\prime$ vertices are the faces of the polyhedron and the edges are the remainder of the edges in the polyhedron which are not in the tree $T$.

Now, for a tree, the difference in the number of vertices to the number of edges is 1. So, evaluating this for $T$ and $T^\prime$ and adding them together, we get the desired formula.